# Force EF navigation collection to reload from DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have two entities connected via one-to-many relationship: Computer entity has many Instances.
I'm trying to develop simple undo/redo mechanism for my appliation.

Redo for DeleteComputerAction just removes computer instance from Entity Framework context (it also clears computer's Instances collection).
But when I want to Undo this change by

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)_dbContext).ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, computer.Instances);
_dbContext.Entry(computer).Collection(e => e.Instances).Load();
```

nothing happens.
May be EF caches the data I want to reload? How can I force to reaload computer.Instances collection from the DB?

EDIT

Actually I have no changes in my DB. I just mark computer entity as deleted in EF context and then immediately try to restore its state form DB. When I delete computer entry from EF context its .Instances collection becomes empty. I just need to automatic repopulate it from DB and that is all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331225/how-to-refresh-objectcontext-cache-from-db

Comment: I do refresh, but computer.Instances collection is empty. Actually I have no changes in my DB. I just mark computer entity as deleted in EF context and then immediately try to restore its state form DB. When I delete computer entry from EF context its .Instances collection becomes empty. I just need to automatic repopulate it from DB and that is all

Comment: I work with old desktop application which has single context during application's lifetime (yes, it is terrible), and I have no chance to dispose context without breaking all the app.

Comment: Why don't you simply dispose context and create a new one ? Also in scenario like the one you have it's better not to delete anything from context *before* delete operation is confirmed but rather use *transactions*. You can create collection and put all items that are marked to delete inside, then if it is confirmed execute query that deletes these items from context and underlying database.

Comment: If you look at the comment on the post that I linked it looks like he had to call ToList() on the collection to get the newly loaded entries.  That sounds a little hokey to me, but perhaps worth a try.